# REST - assign people/group column value to variables

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, people-picker

**EDIT**
Below works by replacing the success code, not sure if the best solution but it works:

```
                    success: function (data) {
                    if (data.d != undefined) {
                        $.each(data.d.results, function (index, item) {
                            myFirstName = item.Manager.FirstName;
                            myLastName = item.Manager.LastName;
                            myEmail = item.Manager.EMail;
                            myDivision = data.d.results[0].Title;
                            myPhone = data.d.results[0].PhoneNumber;
                            myJobTitle = data.d.results[0].JobTitle;
                            i++;
                        });
                    }
```

I'm trying to get information from People or Group column and assign that value to a variable but I keep getting the error alert. How do you pass the value to a variable?

```
var requestUri = webAbsUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Organization')/Items?$\
                filter=JobTitle eq 'Deputy Director'&$\
                select=Division, Branch, Section, PhoneNumber, JobTitle, Manager/EMail, Manager/FirstName, Manager/LastName&$\
                expand=Manager/Id";

            var ajaxOrg = $.ajax({
                url: requestUri,
                async: false,  
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data) {
                    countAjaxOrg = data.d.results.length;
                        if(countAjaxOrg > 0) {
                            myJobTitle = data.d.results[0].JobTitle;
                            myPhone = data.d.results[0].PhoneNumber;
                            myFirstName = data.d.results[0].Manager/FirstName;
                            myLastName = data.d.results[0].Manager/LastName;
                            myEmail = data.d.results[0].Manager/EMail;
                            myDivision = data.d.results[0].Division;
                        }
                },
                error: function (data) { alert("Failed to load your profile."); }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting a lot of spaces added to the URL, creating an invalid REST request.

```
"/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Organization')/Items?$                filter=JobTitle eq 'Deputy Director'&$                select=Division, Branch, Section, PhoneNumber, JobTitle, Manager/EMail, Manager/FirstName, Manager/LastName&$                expand=Manager/Id"
```

Try the following or use string concatenation:

```
var requestUri = webAbsUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('Organization')/Items?$\
filter=JobTitle eq 'Deputy Director'&$\
select=Division, Branch, Section, PhoneNumber, JobTitle, Manager/EMail, Manager/FirstName, Manager/LastName&$\
expand=Manager/Id";
```

Comment: Thanks. I also got it to work after I changed the code inside 'success' I updated my above post with the final code. The error was because I used the display name (Division) rather than the internal name (Title) in select.